# Selenium 3.0.1 is failing to create new remotewebdriver instances

Tags: selenium, grid

After upgrading from selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar to selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar I am getting these console logs after creating each webdriver

> Nov 04, 2016 12:56:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   Nov 04, 2016 12:56:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Here is the a sample code that creates the instance:

`@Parameters("myBrowser")
    public void beforemethod(String myBrowser, Method method) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException{
        RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
        if(myBrowser.equals("chrome")){
            new DesiredCapabilities();
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }`

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),  capabilities); is what is causing the console output. Some browsers will create and the test will run sucesfully, but over the course of the testing, the browers will fail to be created and all of the tests will be skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The warning message shown above means it has initiated chrome or browser instance.This will launch the browser and start execution.  This is valid warning/message in selenium 3.0.

Now for some browsers over the course it will fail to create browser and skip test execution. Here we can enabled the logs at grid node and redirect them to some log files. This will help in identifying the exact problem like null pointer or like this. Log files is best solution to find out solution.
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The warning messages are not harming the test execution, but they are annoying I wish there was a way to suppress them. I also figured out why my tests were being skipped. If for any reason an exception is thrown in the TestNG's beforemethod block then all other tests will be skipped. Simple network errors were causing the entire suite to fail. This issue was fixed by using a try-catch inside of a while loop to ensure that the browser was created successfully